# Checkedchange listener on a checkbox in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

If I have a checkbox in a recyclerview and also have a checked change listener to listen to its events, I find that some other viewholders too get a check even though I didn't check them!!

Is it because the recyclerview reuses its viewholders?
How should I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the recycler view reuses its viewholders. In fact, that is the main purpose of the recycler view, and it allows for much faster scrolling as it is expensive to inflate a view and call `findViewById` for each view instance.

You can overcome this problem by manually setting all the values in `onBindViewHolder`. In your case, this would mean calling `checkBox.setChecked(false)` to put the checkbox back to its default state.

Comment: This will not give me the unnecessary checks, but for every check that I make(checkBox.setChecked(true)), the checkbox is coming unchecked when its onBindViewHolder is called.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the onViewRecycled function in recyclerView and there set the checkbox checkChangeListener to null, set checked to false and call the super method.
worked for me :)